# How to extract only words from a text file in F#?

Tags: string, text, f#

I`m trying to extract only words from a text file that is very simple:

```
Please note that you still have an unclaimed iPhone 7. 

We have repeatedly written to you regarding your delivery details. We do not understand why you have not yet confirmed your shipping information so we can send it to your home address. 

Your special price for the brand new  iPhone 7 phone is only £3 with shipping. 

We hope that you'll confirm your information this time.
```

I have been using this function, but seems that it throws an Exception("No Overloads match for method Split"):

```
let wordSplit (text:string) = 
  text.Split([|' ','\n','\t',',','.','/','\\','|',':',';'|])
  |> Array.toList
```

Comment: Your edit of your code has now made your question incorrect, because the version with semicolons no longer gives the "No Overloads match" error. I'd suggest leaving the original, mistaken code in the question, then adding an extra paragraph saying "The commas should have been semicolons, like this". That way your question will be coherent should anyone find it later via Google.

Answer (score 5):

In F#, items in arrays or lists are separated by the `;` (semicolon) character, not the `,` (comma). Your code is creating an array that contains *one* 10-item tuple. You should write the following if you want an array of ten items:

```
let wordSplit (text:string) = 
  text.Split([|' ';'\n';'\t';',';'.';'/';'\\';'|';':';';'|])
  |> Array.toList
```

If you also want to not get empty strings back as part of the split operation, then you want the [version of `String.Split` that takes a `StringSplitOptions` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
let wordSplit (text:string) = 
  text.Split([|' ';'\n';'\t';',';'.';'/';'\\';'|';':';';'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  |> Array.toList
```

Note that `StringSplitOptions` is in the `System` namespace, so if you don't have an `open System` line at the top of your file, you'll need to add one.

Comment: Yeah, I found that mistake, but still the output array contains empty instances. For example: “Hello, Rmunn” -> output array would be -> [|”Hello”;””;”Rmunn”|]

Comment: Then you want the [version of `String.Split` that takes a `StringSplitOptions` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx). I'll edit my answer to show that as well.